# Label error rate does not reduce on validation data in RNN LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using [this link](https://github.com/mleimeister/ctc_tensorflow_voxforge) to build a speech recognizer. After running this, i can see that after 200 epochs, the training label error rate decreased for 1.023 to 0.085, but the validation label error rate only decreased from 1.347 to 0.843 only. Later the validation label error rate does not reduce any more.

Can anybody suggest any changes in network structure or change in hyper parameters to improve the validation label error rate?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are simply overfitting. The network learns the tiny details of the training set (often just statistical fluctuations), and then fails to generalize, i.e. the loss on the validation set does not decrease anymore. You can try to reduce the complexity of your model in order to reduce overfitting, but eventually it will occur. Early stopping will help you to stop training when the validation loss begins to even increase again. You should also try dropout, and maybe l1 or l2 regularization. This might help to reduce overfitting, but you probably will not completely get rid of it.

With all these things you have to be careful! If you tune the hyperparameters in order to reduce the error on the validation set, you typically reduce the model's ability to generalize. You might want a test set which is used only at the end after the training and tuning of hyperparameters to test whether you have lost this ability to generalize.